# Outgoing Email Settings Not Updating

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I've been trying to update the From Address and Reply-to Address with a
new email address. The update appears to work, however, when an alert
is sent, SharePoint is still using the original email address. I've
tried several different addresses and the original email address is
always used. Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the timer service (SPTimerV3). Sounds like a caching issue. FYI: this belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes i have restarted the SPTTimerV3. didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but IIS needs to be restarted on your sharepoint server for those changes to take effect.